# JMeter Websocket cannot connect to the remote server

Tags: websocket, jmeter, wss

I'm trying to do a webscocket testing for an application on JMeter. The HTTP requests are ok, it displays the background but not the login and password. The result from the websocket is :

> [Execution Flow]
>    - Opening new connection
>    - Using response message pattern ""
>    - Using disconnect pattern ""
>    - Waiting for the server connection for 5000 MILLISECONDS
>    - Cannot connect to the remote server
>    - Waiting for messages for 20000 MILLISECONDS
>    - Leaving streaming connection open
>
> [Variables]
>    - Message count: 0
>
> [Problems]
>
> Entêtes de réponse :
>
> SampleResult champs : ContentType:  DataEncoding: UTF-8

As I said, it always display only background, I need to see all of the page (login and password area too). Has someone a solution ?